# "Rounding endorsement"

Tags: meaning, word-meaning, phrase-meaning

> That sounds like a **rounding endorsement**. Thank you Peter. ([from a BBC show](https://youtu.be/YVTBXnPLa_Q?t=3182))

I can't find a definition in major dictionaries related to this usage. "Rounding" seems to mean "resounding", "emphatic", rather than "concurring" (as in around the group/room), while all the dictionaries I have consulted tend to focus on the mathematical sense of "rounding". Google shows that a "rounding endorsement" is not common but does occur:

> Citing Perkins' extensive background in education as well as being a college professor, Senator Dodd offers a **rounding endorsement** while throwing out some red meat and taking a swipe at the Democratic nominee's challenger...and I think it's safe to assume that we know who the senator was talking about. ([source](http://hatcityblog.blogspot.com/2008/10/senator-dodd-endorses-duane-perkins-and.html))
>
> The party firmly endorsed Lorri Galloway for Mayor. Galloway, who has never lost a race for Anaheim city council, got a **rounding endorsement** from Party chair Henry Vandermeir and a round of applause from the assembled members. ([source](https://www.anaheimblog.net/2014/08/27/galloway-gets-oc-dem-party-endorsement/))

What does "rounding" mean exactly here? Any dictionary sources to back it up?

Comment: This is a good question. I don't have the answer, but I've also heard the phrase "a rounding success." I suspect it is just a degraded form of "resounding" but I can't find any scholarly work to support that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is an "eggcorn", that is a mistake that appears often enough that some speakers think it is correct.  The proper idiom is "a resounding endorsement", but the word "resounding" is quite rare, so some people might mis-hear "rounding" instead, and justify this to themselves as "the endorsement that rounds off the set of endorsements" (or something similar). Nevertheless, although there is some independent use, it should still be considered as a mistake. The proper word is "resounding"

("Eggcorn" is a mistake for "acorn" based on a mishearing+the egg like appearance and corn like properties of an acorn)

Comment: The Free Dictionary has an entry saying “round” as an adjective can mean “done with full force; unrestrained” https://www.thefreedictionary.com/round *gave me a round scolding* I wonder if this is just a rare usage and not an eggcorn.

Comment: I didn’t mean to imply your answer was wrong- I think there’s still a good possibility that this is an eggcorn . There are some interesting entries here : https://www.wordreference.com/definition/rounding but nothing definitive. The lack of dictionary entries is weird.

Comment: There's a good chance it's a confusion between a 'round' endorsement and a 'resounding' endorsement. Because there's a real word 'round' that fits, there's more support for the eggcorn 'rounding'.